# The SMTP server requires a secure connection or the client was not authenticated-- connection timed out

Tags: c#, email, email-validation

This question has been already asked & I've tried each & every thing i found in stack overflow I am banging my head to the wall not sure where the hell I am making mistake, anyway  here is my code.

```
using (MailMessage mm = new MailMessage("sender@gmail.com", txtEmail.Text))
{
    mm.Subject = "Account Activation";
    string body = "Hello " + txtUsername.Text.Trim() + ",";
    body += "<br /><br />Please click the following link to activate your account";
    body += "<br /><a href = '" + Request.Url.AbsoluteUri.Replace("CS.aspx", "CS_Activation.aspx?ActivationCode=" + activationCode) + "'>Click here to activate your account.</a>";
    body += "<br /><br />Thanks";
    mm.Body = body;
    mm.IsBodyHtml = true;
    SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient();
    smtp.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
    smtp.Port = 587;
    smtp.EnableSsl = true;
    smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
    NetworkCredential NetworkCred = new NetworkCredential("sender@gmail.com", "password");
    smtp.DeliveryMethod = System.Net.Mail.SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
    smtp.Credentials = NetworkCred;
    smtp.Send(mm);
}
```

I've tried with changing default credentials to false, what I've notice is when I change port no. to 465 from 587 I am getting connection timed out.

Comment: possible duplicate of [The SMTP server requires a secure connection or the client was not authenticated. The server response was: 5.5.1 Authentication Required](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25660145/the-smtp-server-requires-a-secure-connection-or-the-client-was-not-authenticated)

Answer (score 0):

I think you could be over complicating it. You should not need to use NetworkCredential. It should be something like this:

```
using (MailMessage mm = new MailMessage("sender@gmail.com", txtEmail.Text))
{
    mm.Subject = "Account Activation";
    string body = "Hello " + txtUsername.Text.Trim() + ",";
    body += "<br /><br />Please click the following link to activate your account";
    body += "<br /><a href = '" + Request.Url.AbsoluteUri.Replace("CS.aspx", "CS_Activation.aspx?ActivationCode=" + activationCode) + "'>Click here to activate your account.</a>";
    body += "<br /><br />Thanks";
    mm.Body = body;
    mm.IsBodyHtml = true;
    SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient();
    smtp.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
    smtp.Port = 465;
    smtp.ConnectType = SmtpConnectType.ConnectSSLAuto;
    smtp.User = "gmailid@gmail.com";
    smtp.Password = "yourpassword";
    smtp.Send(mm);
}
```